# Can we animate setContentHuggingPriority?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations:{

        let button = sender as! UIButton


            if button.tag == 0 {

                self.labelDetails.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh, for: .vertical)

                button.tag = 1
            }else{

                self.labelDetails.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow, for: .vertical)
                button.tag = 0
            }

    })
```

I have  two UILabel's which have Default Vertical hugging value as 1(labelDetails) and 251.

The following animation does not work for me. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: you need to add `self.labelDetails.layoutIfNeeded()` inside the uiview animation block and keep the `contentHuggingPriority` code outside the animation block.

Comment: I took the entire code from UIView.animate and used only contentHuggingPriority in the block, but no luck event after that.